# Is there any difference between "a sequence of increasing integers" and "an increasing sequence of integers"?

Tags: grammar

I think basically

> a sequence of increasing integers

and

> an increasing sequence of integers

are of the same meaning.

But since I'm not a native English speaker, I'm not quite sure about this.

Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing. Those two constructions don't always result in the same meaning, but, in this case, they do.

Comment: @Cerberus Why do you think so?

Comment: Iyen, "I think(,) basically(,) " isn't generally sufficient. Let's know if you made any effort to find a distinction, and if so, please share the findings of your research with us.

Comment: They are **not** exactly the same.  "An increasing sequence of integers" could be interpreted as meaning a sequenced which keeps growing, vs a (presumably) fixed-length sequence in which each number is larger than the one before it.

Comment: @HotLicks that's 'could be'. under normal everyday interpretation, they are the same. You'd have to have a very particular context to interpret them differently.

Comment: @Mitch - I could (and, in fact, do) have an "increasing sequence of Facebook posts".  I don't see how someone reading that would think that each post was somehow larger than the one before.  Based the closeness of words, the assumption would be that the sequence is increasing, not the items in the sequence.

Comment: What @HotLicks said. And a sequence that changes somehow from [1,1,1,...] to [2,2,2,...], and then to [42,42,42,...] etc. might also be said to be increasing. The point is that whatever you might think it means for a *sequence* to increase, that is not necessarily (and in general is not) the same thing as a sequence of increasing numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Increasing sequence of integers* and *sequence of increasing integers* mean the same thing: the second number is larger than the first, the third is larger than the second, and so on. In mathematics, *increasing sequence* is what is commonly used to refer to this.

Comment: That's a sequence of monotonically increasing integers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's designate the sequence S thusly:

> S = {i<sub>0</sub>, i<sub>1</sub>, i<sub>2</sub>, ... i<sub>n</sub>, ....}

A sequence of increasing integers means a monotonically increasing sequence, that is, for every *n*

> i<sub>*n*+1</sub> > i<sub>*n*</sub>

An increasing sequence of integers means a sequence of integers that increases without bounds, that is, for every integer N, there exists an integer *n* such that

> i<sub>*m*</sub> > N for all m greater than or equal to n.

This leaves open the possibility that we might have a sequence that contains a subsequence with members that **decrease**:

S = {1, 2, 3, **4, 3, 2, 1,** 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ....}

I hasten to add that this is a technicality relevant to math class.  Informally outside such a class I think most people would consider both phrasings to refer to the monotonically increasing case.

Comment: Source? I'm feeling interested, thanks.

Comment: @Kris This follows from the definitions of convergent and divergent sequences.  Please don't make me look up anomalous examples for an English usage site.

Comment: I agree with @deadrat.  For example, consider a sequence of integers starting with 1.  Now triple it to 3.  Now subtract one.  Repeat.  {1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 15, 14, 42, 41, ...}.  It is a sequence of integers.  It is increasing.  It's an increasing sequence of integers.

Comment: @James I do not call your sequence increasing. I don't see how anyone could. Can you explain how a non-increasing sequence can be called 'an increasing sequence'?

Comment: One might, by choosing to interpret 'increasing' in a different context like maybe mechanical computation, say that increasing means appending iintegers or that particular integers at given locations are changing (getting bigger), but that would nt be the usual understanding in math or nonmath.

Comment: @Mitch: A lot of people say that the global temperature is increasing.  That doesn't mean that every day is warmer than the last.  By the way, I am definitely not a mathematician, so I will definitely bow to a mathematician's critique of my comments.

Comment: @Mitch: Well, I think the following link proves me wrong (at least in the way mathematicians define it).  I change my vote and say that the two phrases are equivalent.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Increasing_and_decreasing

Comment: @James Your link takes you to "monotonically increasing," which is different.

Comment: @Mitch James' sequence is not nondecreasing, but it increases without bound to infinity as a limit (in the sense of my second condition).  Note that I've modified that condition to conform to the mathematical definition of a limit.  This precludes such oscillating sequences as the following:  each odd-index position is 0; each even-index position is its index.

Comment: @deadrat That's avery particular situation you're talking about, none of which is necessarily implied by 'increasing sequence of integers' (or the other one). If every next item isn't greater than the preceding one it doesn't match those four words.

Comment: @Mitch I don't know what "match words" means here.  Definitions aren't pattern matching.   *Increasing* either modifies *integers* or it modifies *sequence*.  In informal usage, they will likely be interpreted the same -- as a monotonically increasing sequence.  In a technical sense, you can drop the monotonic part and still have an entire sequence that will increase without bounds to an infinite limit.

Comment: deadrat, you're right +1, I didn't comprehend that the word "monotonically" was important.  @Mitch: Would you complain about the statement "the temperature in Northern America is increasing from March to July"?  That seems like an equivalent usage of the word "increasing" to me.

Comment: I think this answer is using the phrase "increasing sequence" to mean a sequence whose limit is infinite. That contradicts the definitions on wikipedia and at [wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncreasingSequence.html). Do you have a citation for this usage?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 No, an increasing sequence in general can have a finite upper bound.  But not increasing sequences of *integers*.  The increasing sequences I'm talking about are called "eventually monotonically [or strictly] increasing sequences."  Check *Calculus for Scientists and Engineers: An Analytical Approach*

Comment: @deadrat The answer for English usage is different from that for a domain-specific usage.

Comment: @Kris You mean the answer for non-technical English usage is different from that for "domain-specific" usage.  Hmm.  I know I've heard that somewhere before.  Oh, yeah!  The last sentence in my answer.

Comment: "Monotonically increasing" means little in general English.

Answer (score 0):

They could mean the same thing in general English writing yet be distinct from each other in a specific domain such as mathematics. Context is important (Note the word *integer*: the context is not general usage).

[John O'Connor](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/L8.html) "Theorem: A bounded monotonic increasing sequence is convergent."